# How to show what happened with scikits RBM and LR pipeline?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I'm playing with the RBM that scikit learn provide, I would like to see what happen if I mix an RBM + LR so I do the following:

```
logistic = LogisticRegression(tol=1e-8, penalty='l2', C=4)
rbm= BernoulliRBM(n_iter = 30,learning_rate = 0.06, n_components = 100)
classifier = Pipeline(steps=[('rbm', rbm), ('logistic', logistic)])

classifier.fit(binarizer_training_matrix, binarizer_y_train)
prediction = classifier.predict(binarizer_testing_matrix)
```

How can I show what happened with both matrices at the Pipeline step(i.e. with the RBM and without the RBM?), thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more details on what you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to see both sparse representations(with RBM and with no RBM), just to know what happened in the RBM step and how it created a new representation, thanks for the feedback @AndreasMueller

Comment: I'm not sure which sparse representation you are talking about. After training the pipeline, you can do ``classifier.named_steps['rbm'].transform(binarizer_training_matrix)`` to get the output of the RBM.

Comment: Thanks for the help @AndreasMueller, I would like to do unsupervised feature learning with the RBM. So as I understand RBM could be used as a previous step for classification, probably this will capture the most important patterns hidden in the data. I would like to see the learned weights(sparse matrix?) that are presented to the logistic regression, I am fairly new with DL, thanks!.

Comment: The weights are not what is presented to the logistic regression (and they are not sparse). The expectations of the hidden activations given the weights is what is given to logistic regression.

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback @AndreasMueller. Is there any way to show this expectations of the hidden activations given the weights?. By the way Im working with text, what will represent this for the above pipeline (RBM+LR) for the classification im getting confused?.

Comment: yes, by using the code I showed earlier, ``classifier.named_steps['rbm'].transform(binarizer_training_matrix)``
I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AndreasMueller. I meant; What does the RBM will do to the text?.

Comment: It will extract non-linear features, that might or might not be relevant for the classification task. I'm sure you'll find good explanations of RBMs on youtube or in papers ;)